# Java tic tac toe

Tags: java, arrays, methods, tic-tac-toe

Hi I am writing a tic tac toe game. I have spelled out in comments in my code what I need. What I am having trouble with right now is making a getMove method. I assume I would need to call the getMove method in my if/else statements after the row and column are pressed?

I am unsure about how to go from getting the row/column numbers and putting them into my board
for what the user inputted.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TicTac{
   //declare a constant variable
   public static final int SIZE = 3; //size of each row and each column

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      //initialize the board
      char[][] board = new char[3][3];

      //display the board
      displayBoard(board);

      //prompt for the first player
      //determine if X or O is pressed

      System.out.println("Who wants to go first (X or O)? ");
      Scanner xOrO = new Scanner(System.in);
      String entOp = xOrO.nextLine();
      char enterOp = entOp.charAt(0);

      if (enterOp == 'X'){
           System.out.println("Enter a row (0,1,2) for player X: ");
           Scanner enterRow = new Scanner(System.in);
           int fTurn = enterRow.nextInt();

           System.out.println("Enter a column (0,1,2) for player X: ");
           Scanner enterCol = new Scanner(System.in);
           int fCol = enterCol.nextInt();

      }  else if (enterOp == 'O') {
           System.out.println("Enter a row (0,1,2) for player O: ");
           Scanner enterRow = new Scanner(System.in);
           int fTurn = enterRow.nextInt();

           System.out.println("Enter a column (0,1,2) for player X: ");
           Scanner enterCol = new Scanner(System.in);
           int fCol = enterCol.nextInt();

      }  else {
           System.out.println("Must enter either X or O");  
         }

      //and display the board
      //displayBoard(board);

      }

   //initializeBoard method


   //displayBoard method
   public static void drawLine() {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 9 * SIZE; i++) {
         System.out.print("-");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void displayBoard(char[][] board) {
      drawLine();
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print("| " + board[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println("|");
         drawLine();
      }
      System.out.println();
   }


   //getMove method: to prompt the current player for target position. And place the mark in the position if the position is available.
//    public static void getMove() {
//    
//    
//    
//    
//    
//    }
   //findWinner method: after each move, check the board see if there is a winner



   //hasEmptyCell method: check if there is still empty spot in the board
}
```

Comment: You may refer my answer in below thread. I have used little different logic though - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020757/help-with-basic-tic-tac-toe-program/18284337#18284337

Comment: You have the x/y coordinates of the board.  You need to determine if there is already something in the cell or not.  If there is, you need to prompt the user for a valid row/column again.  If not, you simply need to record the move (`board[fCol][fTurn] = enterOp`) and redraw the board

Comment: I sort of understand. This comes back to my original question though, how would I write a method to get the x/y coordinates and place them on the board?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to get the move.  Bear in mind it has been a little bit since I have played with java.  I'm assuming the 2D char array has null values to begin with. I recommend changing that declaration to and move it into the global maybe:

```
 char[][] board = {{'', '', ''},{'', '', ''},{'', '', ''}};
```

Then I would call getMove after the second read is done like this:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(firstTurn);
int y = Integer.parseInt(firstCol);
getMove(x, y, 'X');
```

You would want to catch an exception since you don't know if the user will actually input an integer.  A loop of some kind (such as while) works pretty good to do this.

Your getMove function should be something like this:

```
public static bool getMove(int x, int y, char player) {
    if (board[x][y] == '') {
        board[x][y] = player;
        return true;  //Here you are returning true to show the spot was available.
    }
    return false; //And here you are returning false to show the spot was not available.
}
```

Comment: `''` is not a valid character

Comment: "move it into the global" Java has no globals.

Comment: Like I said, it's been a while.  I'm sure you can figure out what you need to be doing.  For instance, just change the '' to 'N' or whatever, just to test against.  By global, I meant move it out of the main function so it can be accessed by the rest of the functions in the class.  If that isn't needed then don't worry about it.

Comment: @AndrewJackson I like the effort man! I do get what you're saying about it being global, but my methods are static which can be called upon anywhere in my program. I will attempt what you are saying.